# Как правильно реализовать панель виджетов курса валют и погоды?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Хочу создать вот такие виджеты[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, это лучше делать через CollectionView. Вопрос вот в чем, как сделать так чтобы ячейка с погодой выводилась 1 раз, а остальные виджеты с курсом валют 3 раза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всегда можете использовать разные ячейки для разных элементов в методе

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Что-то типа:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier1, for: indexPath)
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , все работает